# Update resultset with rank

Tags: t-sql

Considering this table:

```
create table t (EventId    int
               ,Section    int
               ,PlayerName nvarchar(50)
               ,Score      int
               ,Rank       int
               )
```

I trying to writing the T-SQL that does have EventId as input and using the `RANK` function to rank by the score but with the sections separated (Ranking individual for each section, Rank 1 for highest score in each section and so on) and then setting/updating the Rank value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET [Rank] = t2.[Rank]
FROM tbl t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT EventId
  , Section
  , PlayerName
  , Score
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EventId, Section ORDER BY Score desc) as [Rank]
  FROM tbl
) as t2 
  ON t1.EventId = t2.EventId 
  AND t1.Section = t2.Section
  AND t1.PlayerName = t2.PlayerName
```

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/117961/) it is running on SEDE.

Comment: Working perfect, wish I could give you more than one up vote!

Comment: @StefanE your wish came true :P